# What is the best way to dual boot Windows and Ubuntu on different drives?

Tags: dual-boot, windows

I currently have a system running the latest version of Ubuntu Studio on a single 1TB WD Hard Drive, and I have recently installed a 250gb SSD into my computer on which I want to install Windows 10 on in order to play games. I have a valid Windows key/license and am wondering the best way to be able to install Windows on the SSD, and have it separate from Ubuntu.

Comment: As far as I know Windows will install its bootloader on the Windows harddisk, and not the Ubuntu one, and vice-versa for Ubuntu, So, I think they already install separately.

Comment: So should I insert the usb with Windows 10 and boot, then install the Windows on the SSD ? I just want to be careful as I already have things on the hard drive with Ubuntu, and wouldn't want to accidentally replace it. Also, how will i be able to choose from Ubuntu and Windows when booting?

Comment: UEFI or BIOS hardware? And then is Ubuntu installed in UEFI or BIOS boot mode. You want to install Windows in same boot mode. Also be careful that IF BIOS, you reset it to use SSD as default boot device. Windows is known to install a 100MB Boot partition at the beginning of whatever drive is default boot. Than can destroy partition table & first 100MB of data also making it difficult to recover any other data on boot drive. Always have good backups. Probably better to make sure SSD is in lower number SATA port like SATA0 and then set that as first boot device. And/or disconnect HDD.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you select the correct drives and partitions when installing Ubuntu and Windows, you should be fine.

Bootloaders are installed on drives, and are **separate** from your computer.

Since the operating systems are on separate drives, they should already be separated from each other by default.

Comment: So should I just insert the flash drive with windows, then boot and install the OS on my SSD ? I am just trying to be careful as I already have things on the hard drive with Ubuntu and wouldn't want to accidentally replace it.  Also, I don't know how I will be able to choose between Windows and Ubuntu on login.

Comment: @RussianBoss2122 you should just install win on the ssd; there should be a key to press to open the bios' boot manager, from there you can select the drive you want to boot from

Comment: @ SahibPrime But will i be able to choose which disk to boot from at startup? or will i have to change it in the BIOS every time I want to load from the SSD or HDD

Comment: @RussianBoss2122 You should be able to access the boot manager. That will have the disks.